# How to add Actor and move it in Unreal Editor?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm new in game development. Pass a training course Get Started (https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/QuickStart/7/index.html) I created a class AMyActorTest extended AActor:

```
#include "TestUProject.h"
#include "MyActorTest.h"


AMyActorTest::AMyActorTest(const class FPostConstructInitializeProperties& PCIP)
    : Super(PCIP)
{
    MyNumber = 12;
}

void AMyActorTest::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    if (GEngine)
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Hello World!"));
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Yellow, FString::FromInt(MyNumber));
    }

}
```

I have a problem that I can not move in Editor to AActor after placing it in ViewPort. I read that I was missing RootComponent for my Actor, but I do not understand how to add it (maybe I do not fully understand actors). Can help you have my source code to solve my problem? This code is doing in terms of training.
My goal - to add an actor and be able to move and rotate it.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this code

```
RootComponent = PCIP.CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(this, TEXT("Root"));
```

to your constructor. That's all. If you'd like to add another components, you can use similar code (this example creates *UInstancedStaticMeshComponent* :

```
UInstancedStaticMeshComponent* instancedComp = PCIP.CreateDefaultSubobject<UInstancedStaticMeshComponent>(RootComponent, TEXT("SubMeshInstanced"));
instancedComp->AttachTo(RootComponent);  // this is important!

// this part is specific to this component 
// (although all are common to other types of your Root subitems)

instancedComp->SetStaticMesh(mesh);       

instancedComp->SetMaterial(0, material);
instancedComp->bOwnerNoSee = false;
instancedComp->bCastDynamicShadow = false;
instancedComp->CastShadow = false;
instancedComp->SetHiddenInGame(false);
instancedComp->SetMobility(EComponentMobility::Static);
```